# Convert a weekly serie in time serie in R

Tags: r

I have a serie in this way:

```
year    week    sale_amount
2016    16        85501
2016    12        74286
2016    14        87499
```

How can I convert it in `ts` so I can use forecast in R?

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the data in the right way, and then follow the example of Rob Hyndman to create a weekly forecast (see line 3 on how to define the `ts` object).

```
install.packages("forecast") 
library(forecast)
gas <- ts(read.csv("http://robjhyndman.com/data/gasoline.csv", header=FALSE)[,1], 
          freq=365.25/7, start=1991+31/365.25)
bestfit <- list(aicc=Inf)
for(i in 1:25)
{
  fit <- auto.arima(gas, xreg=fourier(gas, K=i), seasonal=FALSE)
  if(fit$aicc < bestfit$aicc)
    bestfit <- fit
  else break;
}
fc <- forecast(bestfit, xreg=fourierf(gas, K=12, h=104))
plot(fc)
```

[image]

The code & picture were taken from http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-weekly-data/ where you also will find details on how to apply other forecasting models.

Comment: Thanks, it was really useful